# Making an image visible/invisible depending on the scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, i have a little arrow in my page:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop"><img src="images/arrow_up.png"></a>
```

I wanna make it invisible when the page is at the top and then, as the user scrolls down, to make it visible so the user can click to go back to the top of the page.
 This Javascript doesn't seem to be working:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

I also have this css (which is working):

```
.scrollToTop{
    padding: 1em;
    color: #444;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.scrollToTop:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

I'd apreciate some help! :)

Comment: I would recommend using a js plugin like [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) for this, it will be much easier than building your own.

Comment: What is the problem? Did you add jquery reference?

Comment: Just like @FarzinKanzi said, it looks like you have forgotten to add `jQuery` reference in your code. Please check this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/r72eoa3s/2/) where I have added `jQuery` and your code works without any modifications. I also added `$('.scrollToTop').hide();` so that the arrow is hidden by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your exact issue was this, but copying your code into a JS fiddle revealed that if the page was less than the window height, the arrow would always show.

A fix for this was to include a default `display:none` and then check window height on scroll. Checking it every time would allow the page to grow and shrink and still allow the arrow to only display when needed.

A working example can be seen at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/783dbqj5/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        ShowScroll();
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
});
function ShowScroll() {
  if (window.innerHeight < $("body").height())
  {
    var elem = $(".scrollToTop");
    if (elem.css("display") == "none") elem.css("display","inline");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
  } else {
    $(".scrollToTop").css("display","none")
  }
}
```